# Text underneath an image

Tags: html, image, text

So what I have in an image of a can. What I want is, in HTML, is to have text appear directly under this can. There is other text to the left and under the can, in regular

form.

This is what I have:

```
<img src="URL" alt=" align="right" border="0px">

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 6pt;"><span style="font-size: 20.5pt; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 205);">(header)</span></span></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14pt;">(paragraph)</span></span></p>
```

The header and paragraph here are content relating to the can itself. What I need is text directly underneath that can.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use opacity property to make the <div> on the top translucent.

Comment: What do you have in HTML to cause some text to appear to the left of the can? Please show the context.

Answer (score 2):

Put your image and its accompanying text inside for example a div-element.

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <p class="img-desc">(Image caption)</p>
</div>
```

Then set your styles:

```
<style>
    .img-wrapper {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 1em;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .img-desc { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

You should really avoid setting styles "inline" in each element. That makes the code harder to maintain. You do not need to use those span-elements, just refer to classes on the p-elements to set all the styling for the text.

Comment: +1 but since there is no explicit association between the `img` and the description, do not use an empty `alt` attribute or even better, use [`figure` and `figcaption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/figure)

Comment: Well, all true. I just thought i should give a gentle transition from the deprecaded stuff. I gave no src or alt since the op didn't.

Comment: I should have mentioned this... but will adding the <a></a> code for hyperlinking work with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it seems that the only way to achieve the result is to use a table, replacing the `img` element e.g. by

```
<table align=right>
<tr><td><img src="URL" alt="...">
<tr><td>Text under the image
</table>
```

Using CSS, [other alternatives](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html) are possible, too.